# How to delete a field in a Firestore Document?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

How to delete a Document Field in Cloud Firestore? ... I'm using the code below but I can not.

```
this.db.doc(`ProfileUser/${userId}/followersCount/FollowersCount`).update({ 
[currentUserId]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()})
```

Is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: [Here's the relevant docs for this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can try as shown below:

```
// get the reference to the doc
let docRef=this.db.doc(`ProfileUser/${userId}/followersCount/FollowersCount`);

// remove the {currentUserId} field from the document
let removeCurrentUserId = docRef.update({
    [currentUserId]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this change in the code, but still does not delete the field, I made a test and I can update the value of boolean using similar code, but the delete function does not make any changes in the field.

Comment: See the doc.It should work no? What about your `doc reference`? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

Comment: It was missing `var docRef = firebase.firestore ();` inside the constructor, I changed your code to `var docRef = this.db.doc(`ProfileUser/${userId}/followersCount/FollowersCount`); 
          let removeCurrentUserId = docRef.update({
            [currentUserId]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
        }); ` now worked perfectly, thank you !!!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Comment: `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()` will not work for a field which is already `null`

Comment: You can just use `docRef.update([FIELDYOUWANTTOREMOVE: FieldValue.delete())`

Comment: can someone tell me what happens when the field you are trying to delete doesn't exists on the document ?

Comment: @Saurabh You need to handle run time exception there.

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me. (also worked to delete field with null value)

```
document.ref.update({
  FieldToDelete: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
})
```

Comment: this worked for me for Google Functions Code / Admin SDK code

Comment: Setting the value to null will now save the value as null in Firestore.

Answer (score 24):

### With Firebase Version 9 (Feb, 2022 Update):

If there is the collection **"users"** having **one document(dWE72sOcV1CRuA0ngRt5)** with the fields **"name"**, **"age"** and **"sex"** as shown below:

```
users > dWE72sOcV1CRuA0ngRt5 > name: "John", 
                               age: 21, 
                               sex: "Male"
```

You can delete the field **"age"** with this code below:

```js
import { doc, updateDoc, deleteField } from "firebase/firestore";

const userRef = doc(db, "users/dWE72sOcV1CRuA0ngRt5");

// Remove "age" field from the document
await updateDoc(userRef, {
  "age": deleteField()
});
```

```
users > dWE72sOcV1CRuA0ngRt5 > name: "John",  
                               sex: "Male"
```

You can delete multiple fields **"age"** and **"sex"** with this code below:

```js
import { doc, updateDoc, deleteField } from "firebase/firestore";

const userRef = doc(db, "users/dWE72sOcV1CRuA0ngRt5");

// Remove "age" and "sex" fields from the document
await updateDoc(userRef, {
  "age": deleteField(),
  "sex": deleteField()
});
```

```
users > dWE72sOcV1CRuA0ngRt5 > name: "John"
```

Comment: what if i don't want to hardcode the field value like "age" and use variable instead

Answer (score 2):

***IN CASE THE ABOVE ALL DIDNT WORKED FOR YOU***  (Like me)
use this function

```
const deleteField = async() => {
    firestore.collection("users").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          doc.ref.update({
              date_of_birth: firestore.FieldValue.delete()
          });
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me in  the *admin SDK* context, however slightly adjusted:
`admin.firestore().collection("users").where("userId", "==", userId).get().then((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => doc.ref.update({ verificationUrl: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete() })));`

Answer (score 1):

carefully using this `admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()` Because query doesn't work if you try to delete not available field on the document.

So, I think it's better to set `null`

```
this.db.doc(`ProfileUser/${userId}/followersCount/FollowersCount`).update({ 
[currentUserId]: null})
```

**OR**

```
await db.doc(`ProfileUser/${userId}/followersCount/FollowersCount`)
            .set({[currentUserId]: null}, { merge: true })
```

Comment: Setting the value as null no longer deletes the field, but will set the fields value to null

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works on Firestore v2.7.3 (and probably higher versions)  with python

```
from google.cloud import firestore

obj_ref = db.collection(f"{your_collection}").document("your_doc")

success = obj_ref.update({
    "to_be_deleted_field": firestore.DELETE_FIELD
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason the selected answer (`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()`) did not work for me. **but this did:**

Simply set that field to `null` and it will be deleted!

```js
// get the reference to the doc
let docRef=this.db.doc(`ProfileUser/${userId}/followersCount/FollowersCount`);

// remove the {currentUserId} field from the document
let removeCurrentUserId = docRef.update({
    [currentUserId]: null
});
```

Comment: The part you said that didn't work for you, worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: Setting the value to `null` will now save the value as `null` in Firestore.

Comment: Hmm, @NovelVentures I just tested it and it does remove the value if set to `null`!
I have a feeling you are setting it to `"null"` as a string. 
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
PS: technically speaking, they would never store `null` or `undefined` in the database, ( of course these as string values are not null or undefined anymore! ), even an empty string (or no value) can't be stored.