# Delete a field from Firestore, with a dynamic key

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a single field from a Document in Firestore
The Key of the field is held in a variable e.g.

```
var userId = "random-id-1"
```

In the document I have a field of members structured like this:

```
{
  members:{
    random-id-1:true,
    random-id-2:true
  }
}
```

I would like to delete `random-id-1:true`, but keep `random-id-2:true`

How is this possible without getting the entire members object and writing an updated object?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984308/delete-field-in-firestore-document), however I get the error: `Document references must have an even number of segments`

and I also tried this:

```
db.collection('groups').doc(this.props.groupId).set({
  members: {
    [userId]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
  }
},{merge: true})
```

However I get the error: `Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. FieldValue.delete() can only appear at the top level of your update data`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I have managed to delete a field like this:

```
let userId = "this-is-my-user-id"
let groupId = "this-is-my-group-id"

db.collection('groups').doc(groupId).update({
  ['members.' + userId]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
})
```

This is using the dot operator method described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects)

Please let me know if there are any alternative methods to this

Thanks

Comment: what happen if we try to remove field that doesn't existed in the document?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, here's an updated link to the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields.

Answer (score 7):

I had to import FieldValue

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields

```js
        // Get the `FieldValue` object
        var FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;
        
        // Create a document reference
        var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');
        
        // Remove the 'capital' field from the document
        var removeCapital = cityRef.update({
          capital: FieldValue.delete()
        });
```

Comment: what happen if we try to remove field that doesn't existed in the document?