# Firestore - Delete a field inside an object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore and I would like to delete a field that is in a specific object.
I can delete a field in a document thanks to :

```
fieldName: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
```

But if I have an object like :

```
songList {
songName1: "HelloWorld",
songName2: "AnotherSong",
songName3: "andTheLastOne"
}
```

In order to delete the field songName3, I won't be able to do something like :

```
songList.songName3: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
```

Is there a way to delete a field inside an object ? Or should I delete the whole object, rebuild it without the 3rd field and save it ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47555348/5532513

Answer (score 43):

The "dot notation" with the special "FieldValue.delete()" should work.

Try this:

```
    Map<String, Object> deleteSong = new HashMap<>();
    deleteSong.put("songList.songName3", FieldValue.delete());

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("yourCollection")
        .document("yourDocument")
        .update(deleteSong);
```

It worked for me.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 24):

This work for me in general

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('collection-name')
  .doc('doc-id')
  .set({ songlist : {
    [songName]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
  }
  }, { merge: true });
```

Answer (score 10):

Found this topic today and want to add my solution. I am using the dot notation. The following will remove the specific song from the songlist by using `firestore.FieldValue.delete();`. I am using the Node.js firebase-admin package written in TypeScript:

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
export async function removeSong(trackId: string, song: string) {
    try {
        const updates = {};
        // Dot Notation - will delete the specific song from songList
        updates[`songList.${song}`] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete();
        // Not necessary, but it's always a good practice
        updates['updatedAt'] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

        await firestore.collection('songs').doc(trackId).update(updates);
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your solution I was able to delete a nested field inside an object. 
However, I used firebase.firestore instead of admin.firestore. It seems to be working just as well.

Answer (score 3):

It did not allow me to comment above, but Manuel Borja's solution works and is pretty clean. Here is how I used it:

```
db.collection("coolcollection")
  .doc(id)
  .set(
    {
      users: {
        [firebase.auth().currentUser
          .email]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
      },
    },
    { merge: true }
  );
```

A few things to add: this works when the given field of the map exists and when it does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue from Android using Kotlin, and I solved it with dot notation as well. For Android Kotlin users, that is:

```
 val songName: String = "songName3"
 val updatesMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
 updatesMap["songList.${songName}"] = FieldValue.delete()
 FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                  .collection("Your Collection")
                  .document("Your Document")
                  .update(updatesMap)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Simpler approach to handle maps/object

```
db.collection('Users').doc('key')
        .update({
            'products.keytext' : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Success');
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log('Error---->', e);
        });
```

This will remove object with a key `keytext` from products map.

Answer (score 2):

The new recommended way is to use the exported method deleteField:

```
import { updateDoc, deleteField } from "firebase/firestore";

// Remove the 'songName3' field from the songList map in the document
await updateDoc(yourRef, {
    ['songList.songName3']: deleteField()
});
```

Comment: it's the "v9" way

Answer (score 1):

Caution: This does not work for Maps, only for Arrays!

You might be able to implement `SongList` as an array instead of a Map. Because for Arrays Firestore now has a dedicated function to remove an element from an array:

```
yourRef.update({
    songList: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("SongName3")
});
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 1):

Update the document with a `Map` which has a key you want to get deleted and value `FieldValue.delete()`.

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
collection
  .doc('document_id')
  .update(
    {
      'songList.songName3': FieldValue.delete(),
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const deleteField = async () => {
    const FieldValue = firestore.FieldValue;
    const itemRef = firestore().collection('COLLECTION-NAME').doc('DOCUMENT-NAME');                                
    const res = await itemRef.update(
    'ELEMENT-NAME', FieldValue.delete() //'ELEMENT-NAME' OR Object.Field which equals to Parent Field Name.
)};
e.g.
{ 
    12345: { you: 'You', me: 'Me', we: '12345' },
    56789: { you: 'You', me: 'Me', we: '56789' },
}
const res = await itemRef.update(
    object.we, FieldValue.delete() //OR '12345', FieldValue.delete()
);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.