# Firestore : Update only a key-val pair

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

We have a firestore collection, where each document has only one field `names`.

`names` contains a map.

Now if, I just want to update a single key value pair in that map, is there a way, other than:

```dart
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(namesCollectionName)
        .doc(docId)
        .update(savedNames.toJson())
        .whenComplete(() => {developer.log("Update saved names success")})
        .catchError((error) {
      developer.log("Update saved names failed: $error");
      throw Exception("Update saved names failed: $error");
    });
```

This code updates the entire map.

I am not sure if there is a way to update just a key value pair. I felt it would be more efficient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore processes each entries in the map you pass as a `set` operation on that field.

If you want to [update nested fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) use `.` notation to mark that field. So say you store the full name for each user keyed on the Stack Overflow ID as a map under the `names` field, that'd be:

```
users
    .doc('ABC123')
    .update({'names.13076945': 'Nithin Sai'})
```

If your `names` field is an array and you want to add a certain name if it doesn't exist in there yet, that'd be an [`array-union`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), which looks like this:

```
users
    .doc('ABC123')
    .update({'names': FieldValue.arrayUnion(['Nithin Sai'])});
```

Comment: when ```updating nested fields```, I assume, if the key doesn't already exist, firestore auto creates a key and adds the value. But how does this work if I want to delete a key-val pair (without updating the entire map)?

Comment: You can use `FieldValue.delete()` for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145962/firestore-delete-a-field-inside-an-object

Answer (score 1):

consider the document was set in a form

```
{"bio":{"name":"frank", "age":20}}
```

then you can update age using the code below

```
# First of all set the reference to the document you want to update
ref = db.collection("users").document("frank")
ref.update({"bio.age":12})
```

Answer (score 1):

How it works for me:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore’;

export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(FIREBASE_API);
export const DB = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const key = "age"
const value = 20

const docRef = doc(DB, "users", uid);
await setDoc(docRef, { [key]: value }, { merge: true });
```