# firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete() not deleting field in document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete a field in a Firebase document from a React app using `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()` but it isn't working. Reading and writing data to documents and collections is working fine but I am struggling to get `FieldValue` to work. I've set up the Firebase instance in `src/firebase.js` like this:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

var config = {
  ******
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.fv = app.firestore.FieldValue;
    this.db = app.firestore();
  };
};

export default Firebase;
```

And then in the module that I am trying to use `FieldValue` in I am doing:

```
import Firebase from "./firebase.js";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.firebase = new Firebase();
    this.db = this.firebase.db;
    this.fv = this.firebase.fv;
  };

  deleteFunction(id) {
    this.db.collection("collection_id").doc("doc_id").update({
      field_id: this.fv.delete()
    });
  }
};
```

However no variation of imports or doc references as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984308/delete-field-in-firestore-document) have been successful for me. I don't receive any errors and I know that the firestore instance is working correctly because I am using it to set and read the same data. I have also verified that the `field_id` I am trying to delete is the correct id and that `this.fv` is `FieldValue` by console logging them both.

What am I missing? I feel like this should be super easy and straight forward and that I am overlooking something super obvious,

Comment: I just tried using `"test"` as a field id and did: `this.db.collection("collection_id").doc("doc_id").update({
        "test": this.firebase.fv.delete()
      });` and it worked. Why won't it delete a dynamic field id?

Comment: What is `field_id` in your code meant to be?

Comment: I'm generating some id's for fields on the front end and using them to reference values in a document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you're trying to delete the field that is identified by `field_id`, so say:

```
// THIS WON'T WORK
let field_id = "fieldToDelete";
this.db.collection("collection_id").doc("doc_id").update({
  field_id: this.fv.delete()
})
```

The above code is trying to delete the literal `field_id` field, which probably doesn't exist.

You'll need to use `[]` notation to build the object you pass to Firestore.

```
let field_id = "fieldToDelete";
let updates = {};
updates[field_id] = this.fv.delete()
this.db.collection("collection_id").doc("doc_id").update(updates)
```

Now you're using the *value* of `field_id` in the call to Firestore, and it will delete `fieldToDelete`.

Comment: Ah ok thanks so much! I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Comment: You could also use `{ [field_id]: this.fv.delete() }` - ES6 computed property names (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)