# Firebase firestore remove item from array of field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `Firebase Firestore` to make my website

[image]

As you can see, I have a field `commentList` and its type is `array` and now I want to remove the first item of the array
This is what I did:

```
exports.delete__comment = (req, res, next) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  const {comment} = req.body;

  return db
    .collection('instagram__posts')
    .doc(id)
    .update({
      commentList: FieldValue.arrayRemove(JSON.stringify(comment)),
    })
    .then((doc) => {
      console.log('comment deleted', comment);
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({err});
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

if the item was deleted, I will `console.log('comment deleted', comment);` and it worked

[image]

but the sad thing is it does not remove in the database for me instead, it still there. Please show me how to fix it, thank you so much and Merry Chirstmas

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984308/delete-field-in-firestore-document

Comment: em muốn xóa cả item luôn anh ạ chứ không chỉ xóa mỗi field, em ghi rõ ra vậy cho dễ phân biệt thôi. Em xin cảm ơn anh

Comment: What does your ` req.body;` look like?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `JSON.stringify()` here.  Your array items are objects, not strings, so you should pass an object that fully matches the one to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you converted `comment` object to string using `JSON.stringify`.

Try to use `comment` instead of `JSON.stringify(comment)`.