# How to update a Firestore field to give it an empty value (undefined or null)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore document has a field with a value already set.

Now I want to remove the value by setting it to something that signifies "empty" such as `null` or `undefined`.

So far I have tried doing this with the `updateDoc` method like so:

```
updateDoc(documentReference,{ photoURL: undefined })
```

But it throws this error:

> Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field photoURL in document users/d23xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx12)

And setting it to `null` is also not allowed because if I try to set it to `null` like so:

```
updateDoc(documentReference,{ photoURL: null })
```

TypeScript will throw this error:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'FieldValue | Partial | undefined'.

I found that using an empty string like `updateDoc(documentReference,{ photoURL: "" })` works but it's not as elegant as `null` or `undefined`.

I will use the empty string if no other solutions are found, but perhaps there is another way?

Comment: You could store that as `null` itself just in case you need to query documents where a field is missing or is empty.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I can't set it to `null` explictly because that also throws an error. Sorry that wasn't clear, I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore does not recognize javascript `undefined` as a valid value.  You can see the valid types in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).  Null is a valid type, so you should be able to use that.  If you are not, then you should file a bug against the SDK that you're using.  If you're using the web client SDK, [use this GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk).  Be sure to provide complete steps to reproduce.

If you want to simply remove the field altogether so that it has no type at all, just [remove the field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984308/delete-field-in-firestore-document) and check for the the missing field in the code the performs the query.

Comment: If `null` is allowed then why does TypeScript throw a type error? It isn't typed to allow `null`. P.S. I want to keep the field but give it a `null` value, not remove the field altogether.

Comment: File a bug as described in my edit.  You will need to provide a fully reproducible example that anyone can use to see the behavior.

Comment: Ok will do that now.

Comment: Oops! The TS `null` error was caused on my part, not by Firestore. `null` values are indeed accepted. There is no bug.