# How can I delete a field in Firestore through Unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I need to delete only the database fields in firestore through Unity but I can't. I've tried the example in the documentation but it doesn't work. Any solution?

I've tried the example in the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a field in a Firestore Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984308/how-to-delete-a-field-in-a-firestore-document)

Comment: I'm tempted to trust the samples in the documentation such as the code for [deleting a field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#unity_1). Can you show what you did based on that example, and what result you get? Any information that you found while debugging the problem would also be useful, so I recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) too.

Comment: I followed this example from the documentation exactly. But when executing the delete function, nothing happens. The fields still exist in the database